# hash_hmac translation into Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, hash

I need to translate into Objective-C the following code I received from another developer:

```
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',
                                                  $toSign, $sasKeyValue, TRUE)));
```

I would be tremendously grateful for some help on how to do that. I confess I am somewhat lost on this one...

Comment: Giving the initial language may be useful (php?). Also, there are plenty of question about Hash, Sha256, Base64 Encoding, etc. Have you tried anything?

Comment: looks like php, but didnt get any additional information than just the code. Have searched a bit but I am missing background on encoding